# All boolean fields are false when consuming from the queue

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm using RabbitMQ to publish messages with the payload that contains some `boolean` fields:

```
class EntityDto {
    String name;
    int order;
    boolean isEnabled = true;
    // generated setters and getters for all the fields
}
```

However, when I publish a message to the queue, and consume it on other end, I have such flags equal false. Other fields are serialized & deserialized back properly without any data loss.

To serialize entities, I'm using a `JsonMessageConverter` on both sides (producer & consumer). I tried switching to `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter`, but it doesn't change anything.

What may cause such behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rename *isEnabled* to *enabled* (without prefix is) and rename getter/setter to *getEnabled*/*setEnabled*.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried renaming to `enabled` and accessors to `setEnabled()` and `getEnabled()` and it worked. Also, found out that `isEnabled` will work with `setIsEnabled()` and `getIsEnabled()`.